# Quickblox iOS - Comparing Dates in Custom Object Request

Tags: ios, objective-c, quickblox

I'm trying to do a custom filter on my object request which will return all objects created within the last hour. However, the following isn't working:

```
    NSMutableDictionary *getRequest = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
    NSUserDefaults *prefs = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    // Show vehicles based on the user's selected radius (add filter)

    NSInteger radius = 500 * 1.6 * 1000;
    NSDate *minusOneHr = [[NSDate date] dateByAddingTimeInterval:-60*60];

    [getRequest setObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f,%f;%li",[[prefs objectForKey:@"longitude"] floatValue],[[prefs objectForKey:@"latitude"] floatValue], (long)radius] forKey:@"alertLocation[near]"];

    [getRequest setObject:[NSDate date] forKey:@"created_at[gt]"];
    [getRequest setObject:minusOneHr forKey:@"created_at[lt]"];

    [QBRequest objectsWithClassName:@"Alerts" extendedRequest:getRequest successBlock:^(QBResponse *response, NSArray *objects, QBResponsePage *page) {

        [[self.tabBarController.tabBar.items objectAtIndex:2] setBadgeValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%lu", (unsigned long)objects.count]];

    } errorBlock:^(QBResponse *response) {

        NSLog(@"error: %@", response.error);
        //
    }];
```

Anyone know if it is possible to use the gt and lt operator on created_at date?

Answer (score 0):

You are setting wrong field names to the extended request.
The correct field names are:

- _id*
- created_at*
- updated_at*
- user_id*
- _parent_id*

Checkout this doc for more detailed explanation: http://quickblox.com/developers/Custom_Objects#Module_description

Comment: Link only answers aren't very helpful. Why not bring in the relevant pieces here for future questioners?